# Twitter-Bootstrap: Simple_form not making horizontal form or correct HTML output?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, simple-form

I don't know why Its not duplicating like the example. When I put the following code to have this form:

```
<%= simple_form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name), :html => { :class => "form-horizontal" } ) do |f| %>
<%= f.input :user_name, :input_html => { :class => "span3" }, :hint => "just letters and numbers please." %>
<% end %>
```

Right now it looks like this:

[image]

When I want it to be like this (the first example here: http://simple-form-bootstrap.plataformatec.com.br/articles/new).

[image]

The Problem lies in the HTML being generated. My HTML is:

```
<div class="input string optional">
 <label for="user_user_name" class="string optional"> User name</label>
  <input type="text" size="50" name="user[user_name]" maxlength="25" id="user_user_name" class="string optional span3">
   <span class="hint">no spaces or special characters, just letters and numbers please</span>
</div>
```

And Simple_forms HTML:

```
<div class="control-group string required">
 <label for="article_name" class="string required">
  <abbr title="required">*</abbr> Name
 </label>
  <div class="controls">
   <input type="text" size="50" name="article[name]" id="article_name" class="string required span6">
    <p class="help-block">add your article title here</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Totally different. I'm thinking the Bootstrap generator doesn't generate? What do you think? What should I do?

*resources*

https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form

https://github.com/rafaelfranca/simple_form-bootstrap

http://simple-form-bootstrap.plataformatec.com.br/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Have you added the initializer for simple_form? this initializer sets the wrappers that should be used to output the bootstrap html

```
rails generate simple_form:install --bootstrap
```

Note that this only works with simple_form 2!

Comment: Yeah I did `rails generate simple_form:install --bootstrap` as the installation said. This gave me 3 files: `config/initializers/simple_form.rb` and
      `create  config/locales/simple_form.en.yml`
      `create  lib/templates/erb/scaffold/_form.html.erb`

Comment: Damn, I see now. The bundle install goes to `1.5.2`, so I have to manually use `gem "simple_form", "~> 2.0.0.rc"`. I didn't see at the very beginning that is said "These Instructions are for 2.0...". It was kind of hard to see if you just go straight to the Bootstrap section. Thank you ahmeij.

Comment: from the simple_form github page the correct command is `rails generate simple_form:install --bootstrap`

Comment: Updated the post adding the --bootstrap as per @Dty

Comment: For rails 4, it needs 3.0.0.rc

Answer (score 10):

The output of

```
rails g simple_form:install --bootstrap
```

gives further instructions:

```
Inside your views, use the 'simple_form_for' with one of the Bootstrap form
classes, '.form-horizontal', '.form-inline', '.form-search' or
'.form-vertical', as the following:

  = simple_form_for(@user, :html => {:class => 'form-horizontal' }) do |form|
```

So you must add the `:html => {:class => 'form-horizontal' }` option to each `_form.html` file you want to change the form style. You can use 'form-search', 'form-inline', 'form-horizontal', or 'form-vertical' (the default).

To set the default form to horizontal, edit

```
lib/templates/erb/scaffold/_form.html.erb
```

and change the first line to this (using your preferred form class name):

```
<%%= simple_form_for(@<%= singular_table_name %>, :html => {:class => 'form-horizontal' } ) do |f| %>
```

For those using HAML, the file path and format will be different.

Answer (score 2):

Is your form css set to "form-horizontal" in outputted HTML?

If not, I think you have to wrap the setting of :html :class in simple_form_for tag like this:

```
<%= simple_form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name), {:html => { :class => "form-horizontal" }} ) do |f| %>
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why you marked @ahmeij's answer as correct.

The correct solution is in your comment - you need to make sure you're using simple_form version 2 and not version 1. Like so:

```
gem "simple_form", "~> 2.0.0.rc"
```

or you can do it how [sample simple_form bootstrap app](https://github.com/rafaelfranca/simple_form-bootstrap/blob/master/Gemfile) on github does it:

```
gem 'simple_form', git: 'git://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form.git
```

And incase you didn't run the install the correct command is

```
rails generate simple_form:install --bootstrap
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking to do this with simple_form v3 rc1 then you can follow the steps I lay out here in my blog.  I just researched all of this and implemented it:

http://www.iconoclastlabs.com/blog/using-twitter-bootstrap-3-with-simple_form

Comment: Thank you, thank you, thank you!!  I've been pulling the hair out of my almost bald head all afternoon!   Now I need to go back and try to understand why this worked.  BTW; I am using simple_form 3.0.1 and I had to add the last part that you hoped would be fixed when they came out of RC.

Answer (score 0):

copy config\initializers\simple_form.rb to your app,everything will be ok

Answer (score 0):

I tried quite many different solutions but, nothing helped until I've added `wrapper: :horizontal_form` line to each form inputs. And, I have the latest simple_form version: 3.2.1

For example:

`= f.input :payment_term, wrapper: :horizontal_form`

Hint: [https://gist.github.com/chunlea/11125126/][1]

Answer (score 0):

For simple_form `('~> 3.5')` and bootstrap 4, do the follwing change in `simple_form_bootstrap.rb` initializer:

```
config.wrappers :horizontal_form, tag: 'div', class: 'form-group', error_class: 'has-error' do |b|
```

to

```
config.wrappers :horizontal_form, tag: 'div', class: 'form-group row', error_class: 'has-error' do |b|
```

To change all forms to horizontal, do the following change:

`config.default_wrapper = :vertical_form`

to

`config.default_wrapper = :horizontal_form`

And to change just one form do this:

`<%= simple_form_for(@model, wrapper: :horizontal_form) do |f| %>`

Also you may need to replace all occurrences of `control-label` with `form-control-label` in initializer to vertically align the labels. [Source](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/migration/)